# How to get an image via Web URL and save it to my WEB API DB using Base64 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, api, base64

So, i'm trying to get an image from a URL like "https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/yOIhj8SumRHLD09QzI8tKnri7XguZvtiBFgK" and than put it into my code to convert to Base64.

I'm using this one in controller to convert it to Base64 :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("insertImage")]
    public IActionResult InsertImage(string filePath, Client client)
    {
        client.ProfileImage = _clientService.GetBase64StringFromImage(filePath, client);
       return Ok(client.ProfileImage);
    }
```

And using this code to save the converted image in the "Client" model Context :

```
public string GetBase64StringFromImage(string imagePath, Client client)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

            var clientNew  = _context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == client.UserName);

            clientNew.ProfileImage = base64String;
            _context.Update(clientNew);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return base64String;
        }
```

Once told it, there's a way to get an image directly from a WEB URL and pass it as a parameter to filePath and convert it to base64?
In the image below it's possible to see that my api program only takes images starting from project folder.

[Image of code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zahuS.png)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you just showing code as answer to the question in title? Having some compile issue? Or maybe runtime? Or something does not work as you expect? Make sure to [edit] post with details...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was not so clear as i though. I edited and put some more details. Just want a hint about if is there a way to do that. Just saw people saving image directly in folders but not getting it from web and converting to string.

Comment: So, `await HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(...)` (or similar)?

Comment: So, i can implement this at my controller as an endpoint? I'm really lost, i'm doing a project at my school and neither teachers can help me. I'll look for "HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(...)" to try understand a little more. Thanks.